# EDMX connection string SQL server port

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, port

Does anyone know using an EDMX Connection string in asp.net mvc application, on which port does it connect to SQL Server?

ASP.NET MVC : 4

SQL SERVER Version : 2012

The reason I am asking is because :
I am able to connect to the same SQL Server using ADO.NET Connection string from my local machine

But when I use the EDMX and use EDMX generated Connection String, I get an error :

The underlying provider failed on Open.

Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=14680; handshake=14007;

Connection Strings for reference:

```
<add name="TestConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Server01;Initial Catalog=Tools;User ID=TestUser;Password=TestPWD;Connection Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Apple.ClassLayer.MIS.csdl|res://*/Apple.ClassLayer.MIS.ssdl|res://*/Apple.ClassLayer.MIS.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Server01;initial catalog=Tools;persist security info=True;User ID=TestUser;Password=TestPWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Please share your connstring section in your web.config

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros: updated the question with connection strings

Comment: Have you already tried to remove `Connection Timeout` parameter from connection string? If you want to use connection timeout limit, enable both IPv4 & IPv6 support and ensure the local firewall allows access to TCP 1433 port (or any port set to connect with SQL Server instance).